# Node.js express + React.js pushed to Heroku not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm-scripts

I'm not able to push my repo on Heroku.

I'm getting an error `Cannot GET /`

Here's my structure:

```
server.js
package.json (server)
  /client
    build
    package.json (client)
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "debord_slow_sender",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "cd client && npm start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm server\" \"npm client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "images-scraper": "^2.0.11",
    "ml5": "^0.1.1",
    "node-tesseract": "^0.2.7",
    "pixabay-api": "^1.0.4",
    "request": "^2.88.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0"
  }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `heroku-postbuild` to this:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false && npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
```

Comment: I just tried and it's still not working:  `Cannot GET /` . Let me know if you need more info.